# Core Data fetch returns zero records though table is not empty

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm a Swift newbie, building a Core Data app. I've built and run a [sample app from Ray Wenderlich's site](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145809/getting-started-core-data-tutorial) which works as expected.

I've lifted and modified the following excerpt from Ray's app:

```
var people: [NSManagedObject] = []

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    //1
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    // 2
    let fetchrequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Person")

    // 3
    do {
        people = try managedContext.fetch(fetchrequest)
        print("\(people.count) fetched from Person")
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

This works as expected. However, the following is what I've implemented in my app:

```
var players: [NSManagedObject] = []

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Golfer")

    do {
        players = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

        print("\(players.count) fetched from Golfer")
        // Load any saved players, otherwise load sample data.
        if players.count == 0 {
            // Load the sample data.
            // There are no players to load
            os_log("Loading sample players", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            loadSamplePlayers()
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch Golfers. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

The sample code always returns the full results of the *Person* table and the *person* array count is always equal to the number of rows in the table.

However, for my version, it always reports that the *players* array has a count of zero. Consequently, the *loadSamplePlayers()* method is called each time (which adds three sample records into the *Golfer* table).

Using an SQL Lite database inspector, I can see that the *Golfer* table continues to grow after each invocation of the app.

I'm stumped on why these two, near-identical, code samples should behave differently.

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's the *loadSamplePlayers()* method and *printDatabaseStats()* which is also referenced:

```
private func loadSamplePlayers() {

    let sampleFirstNames: [String] = ["Casper", "Jocelyn", "Arthur"]
    let sampleLastNames: [String] = ["Vitturio", "Brown", "Mullard"]
    let sampleEmails: [String] = ["a@b.com", "fred@x.co.uk", "last@ohm.com"]
    let sampleHandicaps: [Double] = [16.2, 6.4, 27.2]

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Golfer", in: managedObjectContext!)!

    for i in 1...3 {
        let player = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)

        player.setValue(sampleFirstNames[i-1], forKeyPath: "firstName")
        player.setValue(sampleLastNames[i-1], forKey: "lastName")
        player.setValue(sampleEmails[i-1], forKey: "emailAddress")
        player.setValue(sampleHandicaps[i-1], forKey: "exactHandicap")
        // player.setValue(sampleMugshots[i-1], forKey: "mugShot")

        print("Prepare to save")

        do {
            try managedObjectContext?.save()
            players.append(player)
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

        print("There are now \(printDatabaseStats()) in the Golfers table")
    }
}

private func printDatabaseStats() -> Int {
    var count = 0
    managedObjectContext?.performAndWait {
        if let golferCount = try? self.managedObjectContext!.count(for: NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Golfer")) {
            print("\(golferCount) Payers")
            count = golferCount
        }
    }

    return count
}
```

This appears to work successfully as the *print(...)* methods produce the expected console messages and the Golfer table is populated and contains the rows as defined.

Comment: Are you sure your entity name is correct? The tutorial uses "Person", not "Golfer". Can you show the `loadSamplePlayers()` method?

Comment: I've just edited the original question to include the method. NOTE: I'm attempting to implement the technique from the first sample in my own app which uses Golfer rather than Person.

Comment: Hmm, not sure that looks right to me. Are you using the same managed context when you insert as when you retrieve?

Comment: The behaviour I'm seeing would make sense if I wasn't. As much of code is based on samples I'm trying to repurpose, it's possible I've defined the managed context twice. I'll follow this thread and report back.

Comment: Thanks for the steer. I picked through the code and there was a class variable*managedObjectContext* that was setup differently to how *managedContext* was. I made these the same and the issue is now resolved. Thanks again.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it resolved. Multiple managed object contexts are always fun.

Answer (score 1):

Not included in the original question was a class definition, thus:

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext
```

This is defined differently to:

```
let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

yet I was using them as if they were the same. I normalised the two so they are identical and the problem has gone.

Comment: Maybe you can accept your own answer so that it is closed?